# Compile Android VLC

Tags: android, vlc, rtmp

I have been trying to build a video streaming application in android using RTMP protocol. I used javaCV to stream to nginx server. To receive the stream I tried to use VLC android. I followed the instructions given in https://wiki.videolan.org/AndroidCompile/ to compile android VLC code but show error and stops compilation. Is there any other way to compile android VLC. Or is there any other open source RTMP player for andriod?

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to compile it yourself and not use the native (.so) binaries from the official APK together with the java classes from git?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you post the error?
There are basically 2 ways to go for andoid, VLC or ffmpeg.
A ffmpeg based player which should support rtmp is https://github.com/Bilibili/ijkplayer/

Answer (score 0):

use this sample, easy add vlc library by add `compile 'com.damavandi:android-vlc-lib:1.0.0'` to your gradle dependency. there is simple example
https://github.com/m-damavandi/Android-VLC-Sample